# What's the probability of third coin being of 50 cent?

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability

I was asked this question in an interview for Data Scientist position: I have 1 coin of say 10p,20p and 50p each in my pocket. I then draw out of my pocket the coin of 10p. So now I'm left with 1 coin of 20p and 50p each. Call this the 'FIRST' attempt. What is probability of getting the 50p coin in the 'THIRD' attempt?

When I said the answer is 50%, the interview told me it's a wrong answer. Is there some hidden logic to it that I'm not able to pick?

EDIT: When I mentioned 'Third' attempt, the 10p coin is not placed back in the pocket.

Comment: Is the 10p coin placed back into your pocket after the first attempt?

Comment: Maybe the question wasn't about the mathematics but about your ability to stand your ground or make your point?

Comment: If 50% is wrong answer.Then I think we can identify the coin by touch.

Comment: I think the answer is you probably don't want to take that job.

Comment: Are you sure that they were asking the probability under the assumption that the first coin to be extracted were the 10p one? Couldn't it be just an example, and you had to work put P(3rd coin = 50p) with no assumptions on the first two extractions?

Comment: @DaG - Yes, the assumption about first extracting the 10p coin was explicitly mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

A priori, the probabbility that the third coin is 50p is $\frac 13$.
But *given* that the first coin is 10p, the probabbility that the third coin is 50p is $\frac12$.

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

$$P(\text{It is 50p coin in the third draw}/\text{First draw is 10p coin}) $$$$=\frac{P(\text{(50p coin in the third draw)}\cap\text{(First is 10p coin)})}{P(\text{First is 10p Coin})}$$

Total possibilities:$\text{ {10,20,50},{10,50,20}.{20,10,50}{20,50,10}{50,10,20}{50,20,10}}$.

Of these the numerator reduces to $\text{{10,20,50}}$ and the probability of the numerator is  $\frac{1}{6}$ and the denominaotor reduces to $\text{{10,20,50} and {10,50,20}}$ giving the probability $\frac{1}{3}$.

Thus the required probability using Bayes' theorem is $$\dfrac{\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)}{\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Thanks

Satish

Comment: Please edit your answer to make use of \mathrm or something similar to allow standard text in math equations :). Since $this is math text$ becomes $\mathrm{ this\,\,is\,\,math\,\,text}$.

Comment: @Chinny84, could you help me this time to separate text, I shall get the cue from you.  Thanks in advance

Comment: The example above is \mathrm{this\,\,is\,\,math\,\,text} the \, is a separator I forget the spacings but trail an error will help :). Plus I am on a  phone so I can't see the edits properly.

Comment: @Chinny84, Thanks for the guidance, I learnt something new

Comment: You can put the mouse pointer over a formatted text ( like $x^2+y^2$ ) and select 
"Show Math As -> TeX Commands" from the context menue (right mouse button)  to get the TeX source of of an expression.

Comment: @miracle173 I learnt something new :)

Answer (score 0):

If 50% is wrong answer. Then I think we can identify the coin by touch. Then it is **not random selection**.

NOTE: It is a question in **Interview**.